# Tor hidden service on Debian, nginx

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, configuration

On Debian, installed Tor just by going to the website and downloading, extracting whole Tor browser directory to /home/joe/ etc. It renders fine, I've created my hidden service (got the new host name file--URL etc), but my new hidden url does not render. Tor doc says look in logs, cannot find any Tor logs on debian. Cannot find any logs, no vidalia. Without logs, tough to troubleshoot. what is command to add logging for debian?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by looking at your apache configuration. Try loading the servers IP address in the browser and see what pops up. If nothing, then you need to configure the web server, or whatever hidden service you want to be sharing.

Say for example you wanted to share ssh over port 555 from a hidden service, in addition to the relevant syntax in your torrc file, you would also need to set up and configure ssh to listen on that port.

You should also look in your torrc for the location of logs, if the logging function is commented out that would explain why you aren't getting any. Typically on Debian people put them in /var/log/tor

Comment: many thanks, i have the webserver running, page renders at localhost just not at the onion address. i installed tor properly apt-get and now i see log files. will check me apache settings.